# Potestne nōmen «Kayla» Latīnē reddī?

Tags: classical-latin

Quōmodo optimē nōmen «Kayla» Latīnē reddī potest, duābus tantum syllabīs? Nōmina hactenus quae cōnsīderābam: Caela, Kaela, Katja.

Answer (score 5):

Si nomen illud formam femininam nominis *Kay* esse putes, Egger in suo libro nobis blandam appellationem dat: *Catharina*.

Vide: Carolus Egger (1963), Lexicon nominum virorum et mulierum. Romae: Studium, p. 142.

Answer (score 4):

Videtur mihi "Kayla" ab "Michaela" prōdī, similis nomini Latinō "caela". Anglicistī etiam "caela" sicut "Kayla" dicant.

Ergo "Caela" commendō.

(Please excuse my writing, it's been a long while since I've tried to compose off the top of my head like this.)